# WebRequest NameResolutionFailure

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, webrequest

I'm attempting to write a small screen-scraping tool for statistics aggregation in c#. I have attempted to use this code, (posted many times here but again for detail):

```
public static string GetPage(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";
    WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

    stream.Dispose();
    reader.Dispose();

    return result;
}
```

However, some (not all) websites I attempt to connect to that use Ajax or server side includes throw NameResolutionFailure exceptions and cannot read the data.

An example of this is : [pgatour stats](http://www.pgatour.com/.element/ssi/auto/5.0/sdms/players/02/99/10/body/current/performanceStats.html)

I am led to believe the HttpWebRequest class emulates a browser when requesting information so you get the post-generated HTML. Currently, the only way I can read the data is making an iMacro that grabs it from the page source after it runs through the browser. As said before, it works in the browser so I don't think the error is related to a DNS issue and the website does generate a response (.haveresponse is set).

Has anyone else encountered this issue and what did you use tor resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: well, your code with given url works for me, do you have an url that does fail?

Comment: you mean it returns an acceptable string response? What setup were you using? I tested it in both VS2010 and monodevelop and both threw the nameresolution error when attempting to access the given website.

Comment: yep, I used LinqPad, copy pasted your code (after fixing the casing) and run it against the link. Is your webbrowser using a proxy?

Comment: Ahh, that was it! how silly of me! I've gotten it to run in vs2010 now, thanks!
Interesting to note that it still throws the exception in mono, wonder why.

thank you again!