# How to consume a web service using mono for android

Tags: web-services, soap, mono, xamarin

I'm using xamarin to develop an android APP and need to consume a webservice provided by others.I can consume the web service successfully in a ASP.NET application but in a mono for android app I always got a exception showed "NameResolutionFailure"...
I'm a beginer in mono for android, the following is the steps I try to consume a web service in a android app

Step 1: Add web reference:

[image]

Step 2: Consume the web service(http://www.citysupermarket.com.cn/MobileAppService.asmx)

```
AppService.MobileAppService service=new ServiceTest.AppService.MobileAppService();
service.CreateUser("test@gmail.com","123","victor");
```

I got a exception like this
[image]

Can anyone provide some suggetion about this or show me some guides about how to comsue a SOAP web service in a mono for android APP?
I really get stucked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NameResolution Failure means that

```
http://www.citysupermarket.com.cn/MobileAppService.asmx \
```

can't be reached, Can you access the url at All ?

Regarding:

> How to consume a web service using mono for android

I'll say this DOC is quite clear
[docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/introduction_to_web_services](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/introduction_to_web_services)

Comment: I can access the URL using browser directly. Since the service is a SOAP based web service, so I just add web reference and let xamarin to Generate the proxy automatically. Additionally, I have tow computer in  tow different network one can consume the service the other failed, but they both can access the service URL using browser. So I wonder what's can cause the service can't be reached.

Comment: _what's can cause the service can't be reached.
NameResolution Failure
 check this:
[nameresolutionfailure-in-mono-but-not-net] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12922062/nameresolutionfailure-in-mono-but-not-net)
And this 
[webrequest-nameresolutionfailure] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8643950/webrequest-nameresolutionfailure)